# Android The import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I updated and imported google-play-services_lib project and added this library to my project still it is show the same error The import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient cannot be resolved on

```
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
```

and PlusClient cannot be resolved to a type on

```
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
```

Comment: Are you using eclipse ?

Comment: Check google-play-services_lib project is gradle based project ?

Comment: No its Eclipse based project only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlusClient is not available in updated play services.

from [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

```
  private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
    // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
    // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
    return new     GoogleApiClient.Builder(SigninActivity.this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API,   Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}
```

Comment: after added changes like you said, when i try to use  Person currentPerson = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson(); i am getting The method getCurrentPerson() is undefined for the type GoogleApiClient. how can i solve this

Comment: follow the link and read care fully. you can get every thing there.

Comment: Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mPlusClient); insted of Person currentPerson = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson(); it works for me!