# google plus shared url not rendering

Tags: android, google-plus, sharing

I am sharing URL to google plus using `PlusShare.Builder` but its not rendering.

Its render successfully when i simply copy paste URL in google plus, but in android side its not working.

this is my [URL](https://app.instructiveride.com/lyon-france-une-viree-nocturne-dans-la-presqu-ile-de-lyon)

Plz guide me with my code.. is there anything missing in my code.

```
private void shareToGooglePlus(String urlToShare){
        PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(getActivity());

        // Set call-to-action metadata.
        builder.addCallToAction(
                "CREATE_ITEM", /** call-to-action button label */
                Uri.parse("http://plus.google.com/pages/create"), /** call-to-action url (for desktop use) */
                "/pages/create" /** call to action deep-link ID (for mobile use), 512 characters or fewer */);

        // Set the content url (for desktop use).
        builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/share?url="+ urlToShare));
        // Set the share text.
        builder.addStream(Uri.parse(urlToShare));
        builder.setText(urlToShare);

        startActivityForResult(builder.getIntent(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setText("CREATE_ITEM")
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/share?url="+ urlToShare)
        .setContentDeepLinkId(Uri.parse("/pages/create"))
        .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Check the source just in case you don't have something configured correctly: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link

And IDK if addCallToAction can still be of use because according to the docs https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder#addCallToAction(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String) it requires a signed-in PlusClient in the builder, but it is not available anymore in the updated play services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654018/6248510

Hope it helps

Comment: it doesn't share anything? the url is displayed as text without link? the output or the log doesn't give you any hints of errors happening?

Comment: i dont have to check log or anything.. cause i m not getting any error.. it sharing successfully... what my problem is not rendering the given url in google plus via android sharing. but its render successfully when i simply copy paste via browser in google plus.

Comment: your code is nothing but same as me.. i know addCallToAction is deprecated, but its still working for me.. and that not my problem.. i m not finding anything good in your answer.